# I ask for code ideas, the reason why I write below

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

Hello everyone. I have a character like the picture below, I want when playing the game, this character collides with another character, this character will be hidden (Exactly hide the entire skin shirt, okay? , but the character still moves normally) after about 10 seconds, it will show the skin again as shown below.

- I'm stuck in the code. I tried to enable skinnedmeshrenderer , but it forces the sence to reload and it doesn't work very well. If you have any ideas, please let me know. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

So for this you need to look up how to use colliders. You might want a simple box collider, or even a mesh collider. Then you need to tag the colliders (Go to Learn.Unity or the YouTube website to look for some guides if you don't know about these).

Then use `private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){}` and check `col.tag` to see if it's what you want and set the character GameObject to innactive* `character.SetActive(false);`

Then, set a float timer to 10 `timer=10;` and in Update run

```
if (timer > 0)
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (timer <= 0)
    {
        character.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

which will reactivate your character after 10 seconds.

### * Note

If you don't want to turn the gameObject off, you can instead save the mesh in a variable then set it to null for 10 seconds before restoring it

### Alternate solution:

Script used:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] SkinnedMeshRenderer skinnedMeshRenderer;
    Mesh mesh;
    float timer = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        mesh = skinnedMeshRenderer.sharedMesh;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (timer > 0)
        {
            timer -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer <= 0)
            {
                skinnedMeshRenderer.sharedMesh = mesh;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            skinnedMeshRenderer.sharedMesh = null;
            timer = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Shirt before click/after 10s]
[image: Shirt after click/before 10s pass]
*Model "Steve" thanks to Penny DeBylle*

Comment: oh, thank you for this comment, set the renderer alpha value to and from 0 and 1 (or 255 depending on the scale used). This is possible huh. Can you be more specific, would be grateful if you give me an example

Comment: I changed the alternate approach to something a bit easier and smoother. I found this method by just reading the functions associated with a SkinnedMeshRenderer ...reading through intellisense options is the fastest way to solve issues and discover new ways of doing something.

Comment: wao, i'm very happy with your comment , thank you very much

Comment: If it answers your question, please mark it as the answer. I am glad that it helped.